# Lock statement vs AutoResetEvent for LocalDb Thread Synchronization

Tags: linq-to-sql, windows-phone-8, thread-safety, windows-phone

I am writing an application that utilizes Windows Phone's LocalDB feature. I realized that I need to ensure that only one thread is performing operations on a given database, so I have created an AutoResetEvent object to coordinate the various threads vying for access to the database. My code goes pretty much like this:

```
class SomeClass
{
    AutoResetEvent DatabaseLock = new AutoResetEvent(true);

    public async void AddData(Person person)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {

            MyDataContext db = null;

            try
            {
                this.DatabaseLock.WaitOne();

                db = MyDataContext.GetInstance();
                db.People.InsertOnSubmit(person);
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (db == null)
                    db.Dispose();

                this.DatabaseLock.Set();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously that's not the real code, but it's the same general pattern. Anyway, I decided to use the AutoResetEvent object here, as I have seen suggested online in multiple locations. However, I would be inclined to use a `lock {...}` statement instead.

Is there any reason to use AutoResetEvent? I feel like it's slow compared to `lock`ing an object.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `AutoResetEvent` when you need to signal to another thread.

In this case, you're just locking a resource, so the `lock` statement would be a better choice.